# Help with a simple Apache 'hello world' index file. Here is the tutorial I'm using as well

Tags: apache, linode

Here is the tutorial I'm using, just so that you know where I'm places my file. In fact, I'm using the duckling.org example in the tutorial as my own example. Here is the link:

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/installation/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#configure_apache_for_named_based_virtual_hosting

I'm trying to do I simply 'hello world' to see if apache is configured correctly. I've got my vhost files and i've done a2ensite mysite.org, the restarted  and reloaded apache and now i have a static page that says "Index of /" Where do I place my html file that prints out hello world? I thought I could just create an index.html file in /srv/www/ducklington.org/ with the html and it would print but that's not the case. :/ I'm trying to do I simply 'hello world' to see if apache is configured correctly. I've got my vhost files and i've done a2ensite mysite.org, the restarted  and reloaded apache and now i have a static page that says "Index of /" Where do I place my html file that prints out hello world? I thought I could just create an index.html file in /srv/www/ducklington.org/ with the html that says 'hello world' and it would print but that's not the case.

j.

Comment: Mabe you should try to ask at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to place the my .html file *not in the root folder* but in public_html instead. After that, I get my hello world.